# User fields seem empty when the user is has been registered

Tags: php, laravel

I added couple new columns to users table like `role`, `suspended_at` and `banned_at`. And then added them as fillable.

But when a new user is registered, the fields seems empty (except `id`,`created_at` and `updated_at`).

**Here is the migration file**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string("username", 20)->unique()->index();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string("role",15)->default("newbie");
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime("suspended_at")->nullable();
        $table->dateTime("banned_at")->nullable();
    });
```

**User model**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', "username", "role", "suspended_at", "banned_at"
    ];
```

**a small demo from users table.**

```
+----+------+----------+-------+----------+------+
| id | name | username | email | password | role |
+----+------+----------+-------+----------+------+
|  4 |      |          |       |          |      |
+----+------+----------+-------+----------+------+
```

**RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        "username" => $data["username"],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `But when new user registered` Can you share the code where you actually persist the user in db

Comment: @AngadDubey I edited my question

Comment: First of all you should add some validation. Secondly try dumping the incoming data `dd($data)` to inspect what is actually coming in.

Comment: @AngadDubey they are already validated and of course I dumped incoming data before creating new user, it seems fine. I also checked laravel.log, there is no error about that

Comment: Is this a form? Your controller looks wrong. it should be `function create(Request $request){}` and then pass your variables in like `$request->name` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests

Comment: @fyroc it's default laravel RegisterController, all I did is just adding username field

Comment: Default for laravel as of 5.* uses `Request`. What version are you using?

Comment: @fyroc it was 5.6 but I updated to 5.7 currently

Comment: Ok then try my suggestion.

Comment: You are correct though, the default Auth is not using Request

Comment: @fyroc I dumped $data variable before and it was full of with fields, there is no problem with that

Comment: Try just creating your own controller instead of using Laravels.

Comment: Have you checked your db structure to see if the new columns have been correctly created?

Comment: Also try using `DB::enableQueryLog();` before and `DB::disableQueryLog();` after your query. So you know what is the SQL sentence(s) performed by laravel. Btw, you get this query log doing: `$the_log = DB::getQueryLog();`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add `role, suspended_at, banned_at` inside `User::create` to register. And also in your table you don't have `suspended_at, banned_at` column, please check once.

Instead of using default registration I am suggesting you to create your own controller `php artisan make:controller UserController` then add a `post-url` to indicate/trigger the function like `Route::post('/register', UserController@add_new_user)` and then inside the controller you have to call the model by adding `use App\User` before `class UserController extends Controller` and inside the class create your own function like below:

```
public function add_new_user(Request $request) {
  $user = new User; //modal
  $user->name = $request->name;
  $user->username = $request->username;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  .
  .
  .
  $user->save();
}
```